# Why was Rhodes following Barton?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, hawkeye

At the beginning of *Avengers: Endgame* (2019), we learn that Hawkeye

> loses his entire family to the Snap occurring at the end of *Avengers: Infinity War* (2018). This made him turn into a rogue assassin, or probably Ronin.

Colonel Rhodes told Black Widow that he was chasing him. What were his intentions?

> Was he planning to bring him to justice?

We also see him at the end at

> Tony Stark's funeral,

A few meters behind Rhodes. Was he forgiven?

Comment: We might need to wait till the Hawkeye show to figure out what is happening with him.

Comment: It seems clear that Rhodes was simply keeping tabs on Hawkeye for Natasha, not attempting to bring him to any kind of justice. "NATASHA ROMANOFF: Will you find out where he's going next? 
RHODEY: Nat... 
NATASHA ROMANOFF: Please. "

Also - he was only taking out bad guys..so...

Comment: @NKCampbell Sokovia accords were there just to prevent these vigilantes acting on their own. So I hardly think him taking out the bad guys make him any less criminal.

Comment: we're going to re-litigate Civil War here? ;)

Comment: Also, he was already chasing Barton, Natasha just wanted inside information from Rhodes about his next destination.

Comment: Who marked this question as primarily opinion based? Either we know what his intentions (through novelisation of the movie), or we don't know it (yet). There is no opinion about this question.

Comment: Just about everybody to ever exist as a hero was at Tony Stark's funeral...

Comment: At least, the alive ones.

Comment: Rhodes wanted to join in on some petty non-powered criminal beatdowns or murders too?

Answer (score 10):

Because Nat asked him to because of what he was doing over the world. This is made explicit in the scene where Nat and Rhodey are talking and she does *exactly that*. Of course it's worth noting that Rhodey could also be acting off of his own back here and he might have been initially but he seems somewhat reluctant to which indicates that Nat was the one asking him to all along.

> **Natasha Romanoff:** Where are you?
>
> **James Rhodes:** Mexico. The federales found a room full of bodies. Looks like a bunch of cartel guys. Never even had the chance to get their guns off.
>
> **Natasha Romanoff:** It's probably a rival gang.
>
> **James Rhodes:** Except it isn't. It's definitely Barton. What he's done here, what he's been doing for the last few years... I mean, the scene that he left... I gotta tell you, there's a part of me that doesn't even want to find him.
>
> **Natasha Romanoff:** Will you find out where he's going next?
>
> **James Rhodes:** Nat...
>
> **Natasha Romanoff:** Please.
>
> **James Rhodes:** Okay.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

There is further evidence that Nat is the one in charge and controlling clean up in that she is staying at HQ and seems to be coordinating efforts between the Avengers.

> **Natasha Romanoff:** Alright. Uh, well. This channel is always active. So, if anything goes sideways... anyone's making trouble where they shouldn't... comes through me.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

They are clearly following him because of his quest of murder and destruction to either try and bring him in and reason with him or to stop him altogether. When Nat finally goes to find him herself this is exactly what she does, she reasons with him and essentially gives him a bit of a slap on the wrist.

> **Clint Barton:** You shouldn't be here.
>
> **Natasha Romanoff:** Neither should you.
>
> **Clint Barton:** I've got a job to do.
>
> **Natasha Romanoff:** Is that what you're calling this? Killing all these people isn't gonna bring your family back.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

No was he forgiven at the end? I wouldn't blankly state he was forgiven for what he did during the Blip but he did a ***lot*** to make up for it. He was a vital member during the Time Heist and he helped defeat Thanos' forces in the Battle of Earth, he more than made up for it./ Of course with losing Nat and everything else that happened it's hardly a leap to assume that quite a lot of it has been swept under the rug as there have been bigger things to worry about now.

Comment: The first sentence is obviously wrong. Romanoff asked for insider information about Hawkeye's whereabouts. There is no indication that Rhodes went to Mexico for Romanoff. In fact, the quote supports this: "probably a rival gang". Romanoff didn't even know Rhodes' reason to be there.

Comment: @C.Koca Nat is lying to herself because she doesn't want to believe what Clint is doing... she is in denial. She knows exactly what is going on when Rhodey says it in more detail.

Comment: Her being in denial does not imply she knew Rhodes' intentions to go to Mexico. She didn't even know he was in Mexico. What I understood is that she knew Barton was on a killing spree and Rhodes was trying to handle it. Rhodes was not acting on Romanoff's orders, at least there is no evidence suggesting your POV.

Comment: @C.Koca I think there's more evidence suggesting he was there on her orders not of his own accord considering the conversation they have. It's also worth noting she could have ordered him to follow Clint but not know where he is, she isn't saying "go to Mexico to find Clint" but "find Clint" because she doesn't know where he is.

Comment: Romanoff is quite clearly coordinating cleanup and containment efforts: "NATASHA ROMANOFF: Alright. Uh, well. This channel is always active. So, if anything goes sideways... anyone's making trouble where they shouldn't... comes through me. "  As well as her asking Okoye "How are we handling it?" who replies, "We handle it by not handling it", additionally, Danvers telling her that she [Danvers] won't be back on Earth for a while because she is single handledly doing for thousands of other planets what Natasha and the others are doing for Earth alone

Comment: @NKCampbell Good point, meant to add that in but forgot. The whole scene clearly shows Nat in charge,

Comment: Also also the conversation immediately after w/ Rogers and Natasha: "If I move on, who does this?"

Comment: Then why would she "beg" to learn his next location? Romanoff may be coordinating the general effort but she definitely was not in charge on Barton pursuit.

Comment: @C.Koca If she wasn't in charge Rhodey wouldn't have gone... he clearly didn't want to. She's just asking him nicely because... well... she's nice. and she's tired of the situation etc. etc.

Comment: Because Rhodes is friend's with Barton as well...he says he partly doesn't want to find him, because he would like the comfort of being able to deny what Barton has become ie: "maybe it's not him, if I don't find him, maybe I can believe that" - she is saying, "please, I don't want it to be true either but we need to know"

Comment: You are just conjecturing. He didn't want to go but him going does not necessarily mean he goes on Romanoff's orders. He might be acting on higher orders like from Secretary (probably of State).

Comment: @C.Koca Oh course it's speculation, informed speculation but speculation still, because we get nothing explicit only the implicit mentions (very heavily implied mentions of course). I think we'll have to agree to disagree on this though.

Comment: @C.Koca - if the scene isn't clear - I'd vote to close as POB :\

Comment: I hear him answering to the Secretary of State in Infinity War. When I hear Romanoff begging for information, I know that his work is not related to whatever she is coordinating. From my point of view, I am reading the scenes as they are played.

Comment: @NKCampbell "We don't know" is a very acceptable answer. You are not using close votes as they are intended.

Comment: @C.Koca You mean he "answers to the Secretary of State" when he denies the order and does a "court martial offence"? I'm no expert but that seems like the exact opposite.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot That is, he was. If he wasn't answering why would he say "That is court marshall?"

Comment: @C.Koca Now we're going to play semantics to be honest, he _was_ under their command but he wasn't necessarily following their orders. As of IW though he seems to have quite literally turned his back on them.

Comment: Sure - he was ostensibly operating under the accords in IW, but when he then told Ross "all over it" (ie "yes sir, I'll do it") then closed the window and ignored what Ross said, he stated "that's a court-martial" - meaning "well...I disobeying an order, I'm on your side now Cap". The question isn't about IW though, it's about EG, and the scene in question is also 5 years from later from IW

Comment: This answer should be marked as correct; you're not going to get a better one, even with Hawkeye just wrapping up. There's no mention of Rhodes in there